# Why did git push origin master draw ASCII art?

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I ran `git push origin master`,
I saw a very unusual ASCII picture.
I have run `git push` hundreds of times and have never seen this before.
Is there any explanation for what it means?

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 1.05 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: ++++                               ++++
remote:   +++++++                     +++++++  
remote:      +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++     
remote:          +++++++++++++++++++++         
remote:                 +++++++                
remote:       +++                     +++      
remote:       ++++++     +++++     ++++++      
remote:        ++++++    +++++    ++++++       
remote:        +++++++    +++    +++++++       
remote:         ++++++++   +   ++++++++        
remote:          ++++++++     ++++++++         
remote:            ++++++++ +++++++++          
remote:             +++++++++++++++             
remote:              +++++++++++++              
remote:                +++++++++                
remote:                  +++++++                
remote:               +   +++++++               
remote:              +++   +++++++              
remote:             ++++++  +++++++             
remote:            +++++++   +++++++            
remote:           +++++++     +++++++           
remote:          +++++++       +++++++           
remote:          +++++++       +++++++           
remote:          +++++++       +++++++           
To git@bitbucket.org:my-name/my-project.git
   57367b4..3148737  master -> master
```

I am running OS X 10.7.5.

The picture actually has rainbow colors and looks like this.
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

bitbucket did this to celebrate the Supreme Court decision. More generally, anything printed out by a post-receive hook on the server is visible to the client after a push.

Answer (score 0):

When pushing to a Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) repo something similar happens.  This is just the logo of the repo you are communicating with, in this case bitbucket.  Perhaps you have never seen this behavior before because they recently updated their software.  Nothing to be concerned about.