# Weird image in git push origin master

Tags: git, bitbucket

What is this? [it looks like a big C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFMUq.png). First time it happened to me in git push.

Comment: [have a look at the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095210/why-did-git-push-origin-master-draw-ascii-art) It’s ascii art emmited from a post receive hook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had that too. It's a Bitbucket thing. It seems they do this every year at around this time.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-discussions/Do-we-really-need-ascii-art-in-a-push-response/td-p/599644

Answer (score 0):

This particular one is a Pride Day thing, specific to Bitbucket: https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/8sc2fp/happy_pride_bitbucket_easter_egg_upon_pushing/